# Python pandas - merge csv files in directory into one

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a directory with `csv` files:

```
frames/df1.csv
       df2.csv
```

frames are structured like this:

`df1.csv`

```
               artist            track        plays
1            Pearl Jam           Jeremy         456
2   The Rolling Stones   Heart of Stone         546
```

`df2.csv`

```
                artist            track        likes
3            Pearl Jam           Jeremy         5673
9   The Rolling Stones   Heart of Stone         3456
```

and I would like to merge all frames into one, ending up with:

```
              artist            track          plays       likes    
0          Pearl Jam           Jeremy            456        5673       
1 The Rolling Stones   Heart of Stone            546        3456
```

I've tried:

```
path = 'frames'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
list_ = []
for file_ in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

to no avail. what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just simply using your code create the list of DataFrame

```
path = 'frames'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
l= []
for file_ in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    l.append(df)
```

Then using `functools.reduce`, merge the list dataframe into one

```
import functools
l= [df1, df2, df3....]
merged_df = functools.reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['artist','track']), l)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.join` is useful. Its analogous to a SQL join. Something like:

```
df1.join(df2, on=('artist', 'track'))
```

Comment: oh well `join` makes assumptions about indexing. `merge` mentioned in other solutions is the proper choice when you don't want to go about normalizing all the indexes for your dataframes.